# Hudson has problem with subversion plugin

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

When execute svn update whent in repository there are any changes it gets next error

> FATAL: tried to access method
>   hudson.scm.ChangeLogSet$Entry.setParent(Lhudson/scm/ChangeLogSet;)V
>   from class
>   hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to
>   access method
>   hudson.scm.ChangeLogSet$Entry.setParent(Lhudson/scm/ChangeLogSet;)V
>   from class
>   hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet     at
>   hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet.(SubversionChangeLogSet.java:65)
>     at
>   hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogParser.parse(SubversionChangeLogParser.java:71)
>     at
>   hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogParser.parse(SubversionChangeLogParser.java:43)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild.calcChangeSet(AbstractBuild.java:701)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild.access$600(AbstractBuild.java:90)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:513)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:424)
>     at
>   hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1363)
>     at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
>     at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
>     at
>   hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:145)

I see this bug in Hudson 2.0.0 http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-8837 But I have 2.0.1 version and still get this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was fixed in version 2.0.1 (2011-06-02) of the [Subversion Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Subversion+Plugin).
You can update it on the `http://your-hudson-server:8080/hudson-2.0.1/pluginManager/` Page.

Comment: Thanks bobndrew. I tried doing this today, to get over the same problem Dmitro mentioned. After downloading and installing the upgrade, I had to restart Hudson. When it came back, there was no Subversion plugin at all. I could get back the 2.0.0 plugin by deleting all the subversion files/directory from hudson/plugins and restarting tomcat. Any hints? http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Subversion+Plugin?focusedCommentId=54329443&#comment-54329443

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't offer any help. The update of my SVN-Plugin worked without any problem.

Comment: I am already using hudson-2.0.1 version but still getting the error FATAL: tried to access method hudson.scm.ChangeLogSet$Entry.setParent(Lhudson/scm/ChangeLogSet;)V from class hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method hudson.scm.ChangeLogSet$Entry.setParent(Lhudson/scm/ChangeLogSet;)V from class hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet

Comment: look version of your Subversion Plugin in Hudson, bug is fixed in 2.0.1 version of this plugin. I had Subversion Plugin 2.0 in Hudson 2.0.1